# JPA why is MapJoin value() path needed

Tags: dictionary, jpa, join, key-value

JPA: Map join value() path example,

```
@Entity
public class Book {
   @OneToMany
   @MapKey
   Map<Long, Chapter> chapters;
}

@Entity
public class Chapter {
    @Id Long id;
    String name;
}



CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createCriteriaQuery(Book.class);
Root root = criteriaQuery.from(Book.class);
MapJoin<Book, Long, Chapter> chapters = (MapJoin)root.join("chapters");
Path chapterName = chapters.get("name")
// or
Path chapterName = chapters.value().get("name");
```

What is the difference between the last two lines? Map join is the join to the map value type, why value() is needed?

Comment: That won't compile. join() doesn't return a Map. Post code that compiles, and that doesn't use raw types. Then we can discuss what this code does.

Comment: Fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I think your code does not compile.
Anyway - because the join to chapters gives back a MapJoin.
And Map always consist of a Key and a Value.

So if you want to access the value (e.g. the Chapter) then you have to call value().

```
CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Book.class);
Root root = criteriaQuery.from(Book.class);
MapJoin join = root.join(Book_.chapters);
Path path = join.value().get(Chapter_.name);
```

Comment: MapJoin<Book, Long, Chapter> chapters = (MapJoin)root.join("chapters");
Path chapterName = chapters.get("name"); It gives the same path. right? because the map join target type is Chapter.

Comment: To quote the javadoc for `MapJoin.value()`: 'Create a path expression that corresponds to the map value. This method is **for stylistic use only**: it just returns this.'